# Why are my DOM variables retaining value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to create an archive display of database information. I would like the end result to look something like this..

> - 2018
>
>   - January
>
>     - item1
>     - item2
>   - April
>
>     - item 1

The problem I am having is that my month and item values are not clearing and end up nesting themselves back into the previous month as well. I believe I have pinpointed where the flaw in logic lies but I can't seem to fix it. Any help woould be appreciated. My function looks like so...

```
 function buildBooklistArchive( $, response  ) {

     var years = [];

     response.forEach( function(el) {

        var yearContainer = $("<ul>");
        var year = $("<li>").addClass("year-" + el.YEAR);
        var monthContainer = $("<ul>");
        var month = $("<li>").addClass("month-" + monthConverter(el.MONTH) );
        var titleContainer = $("<ul>");
        var currentMonth = "";

            if ( $.inArray(el.YEAR, years) === -1 ) {

              years.push(el.YEAR);
              currentMonth = monthConverter(el.MONTH);
              year.append("<h1>" + el.YEAR + "</h1>");
              month.append("<h4>" + currentMonth + "</h4>");
              var titles = el.booklists.split(",");

              titles.forEach( function (e) {
                   titleContainer.append(e);
              });

              month.append(titleContainer);
              monthContainer.append(month);
              year.append(monthContainer);
              $(".archive-list").append(year);

           }

           else {   
               currentMonth = monthConverter(el.MONTH);
               month.append("<h4>" + currentMonth + "</h4>");
               var titles = el.booklists.split(",");
               titles.forEach( function (e) {
                   titleContainer.append(e);
               });

            month.append(titleContainer);
            $( '.year-' + el.YEAR + ' ul' ).append( month.hasClass("month-" + currentMonth) );
      }


     });

}
```

So whats happening is that when I get into the else statement month is still holding the value of the previous month and attaches iteself into the bottom of the previous list items. My thinking would this variable would get reset upon each iteration of the loop but maybe its different for DOM elements? The output I am getting looks something like this..

> - 2018
>
>   - January
>
>     - item1
>     - item2
>     - April
>
>       - item 1
>   - April
>
>     - item 1

Comment: what are "DOM variables"?

Comment: I think you want to use .html instead of .append.

Comment: by that i mean the variables I am using to hold my DOM elements( i.e. var monthContainer = $("<ul>"); )

Comment: What happens in your monthConverter? As @Scottie said, you can use .html to clear up the DOM element(s) before adding new elements before looping, or alternatively check the el inside the append logic and remove old values if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simpler than I thought. The variables were getting reset like I originally thought but I was appending the end result to multiple places instead of just the month container. It should have been  monthContainer.append( month ) on the last line.